# How to force terminate a cloud foundry app

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an app running in cloud foundry which has been working fine for months, but has suddenly stopped responding. The errors in the log are all related to connecting to a postgres database service. I don't really know how to administer this sort of thing in cf, so I decided to just remove the app and service and redeploy from scratch.
However I can't remove the app or service - all requests are blocked due to an in progress operation between the app and service.
For example:
Job (ac7753ee-19e8-4b7a-9f39-85284167fb7d) failed: The service broker rejected the request due to an operation being in progress for the service binding.
So I can't delete the app because it is bound to the service, and I can't unbind the app and service because there is an operation in progress.
What can I do?

Comment: maybe you can kill it `cfd ssh appname --command "kill -9 -1"`

Answer (score 1):

For now, to get you unstuck you could try `cf purge-service-instance` instead, this removes the service instance without making a call to the broker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However it doesn't let me: Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10007, message: Your token lacks the necessary scopes to access this resource. I own the tenant and the space and I created the service instance and the app, so not sure why I haven't got permission

Comment: Do you have the "Space Developer" role for the space it is in? Just wondering if it's worth getting the guid for the service and trying to delete it by calling the CF API directly using the `cf curl` command. http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.115.0/index.html#delete-a-service-instance

Comment: You may want to reach out to one of your platform operators. Something is messed up with the broker and that would be on them to fix. It's almost certainly related to why your app stopped working in the first place. You could purge the instance, I'm kinda surprised that you are not allowed to do that, but that would leave whatever mess is on the broker stranded there. If your company has implemented charge-back or you're on a public PaaS and paying for the service, it'll probably keep billing you until things are cleaned up properly.

Comment: I tried deleting the service directly using the guid, but it does the same thing really - now the service shows as "delete failed"